# How do you ensure deep link when deploying Angular 6 to Azure web app

Tags: angular

I am trying to deploy an Angular app to an Azure web app, however deep link does not work.

angular.json:

```
"assets": [
"src/favicon.ico",
"src/assets",
"src/coreui",
"src/web.config"
```

I added a web.config in the src folder:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
     </staticContent>

      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: DashboardComponent,canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]},  
  {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},  
  {path:'logout', component: LogoutComponent},  
  {path:'reports',component: ReportsComponent,canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]}, 
  {path:'dashboard',component: DashboardComponent,canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]},
  {path:'assets/:id',component: AssetsComponent,canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard]}
];
```

index.html:

```
<base href="">
```

Is there more settings to set? Notice the app is deployed with a asp.net core 2.1 api project. I dont know if this kind of application will conflict with appsettings.json or of this should still work?

Comment: Why the downvotes are more information needed or is it dublicate question?

Comment: I got you @Thomas ....it's a very interesting question, +1

Comment: I found a solution. I will post later when I am home.

Comment: That must have been a long trek home :p